# XML Parsing Error: no element found Location

Tags: asp.net, ajax, xml

When I work in my local host, it is working fine. No issues.

When I deployed my code to the server, This error occurs only to One page in my application. All other pages works fine.

I tested in IE, Chrome and Firefox browsers. In IE and Chrome, it is showing blank page. I checked in developer tools and found that there is no content. In Firefox, it is showing the below error.

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found
```

Location: create.aspx
Line Number 1, Column 1:
^

The other thing I am using differently from other pages is the toolscript manager.

In other pages, I am using script manager.

What would be the reason behind this ?

Comment: when exactly the error occurs? at page lead time or when u click any button?

Comment: @ijaz Hello, At page load only